# loop json array and return values in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I use a library for Synchronize a local WebSQL DB to a server specifically https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync. I use PHP: 5.4.7
this is json var $json

```
{
"info":"",
"data":{
    "clientes":[],
    "conceptos_gastos":[],
    "formaspago":[{
        "idFormaPago":7,
        "FormaPago":"quwuw",
        "Dias":1,
        "Cuotas":1,
        "last_sync_date":null
    }],
    "listaprecios":[],
    "producto":[],
    "repartidores":[],
    "tipodocumento":[],
    "vehiculos":[],
    "zonas":[]
}
}
```

when I try to get the values

```
$js=json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($js['formaspago'] as $row ) {
   echo $row["Formapago"];

}
```

I get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach

any help is appreciated

Comment: Add your php code as well.

Comment: Hint: `$js['data']['formaspago']`

Comment: You should learn to debug your code. Try to add this right before the foreach line, it will pretty-print your array. It's quite obvious that the key $js['formaspago'] doesn't exist, it's really $js['data']['formaspago']... echo '<pre>'; var_dump($js);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
//array
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data["data"]["formaspago"] as $row) {
    echo $row["Formapago"];
}
```

Thanks @JimL for the hint.

Comment: json_decode($json) returns an object. json_decode($json, true) returns an array :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing a valid array to the `foreach` loop. However, even if you parse the json you've supplied, a `foreach` won't work because it's an object not an array.

```
$json = '{
"info":"",
"data":{
    "clientes":[],
    "conceptos_gastos":[],
    "formaspago":[{
        "idFormaPago":7,
        "FormaPago":"quwuw",
        "Dias":1,
        "Cuotas":1,
        "last_sync_date":null
    }],
    "listaprecios":[],
    "producto":[],
    "repartidores":[],
    "tipodocumento":[],
    "vehiculos":[],
    "zonas":[]
}
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
```

`print $obj->info` will return an empty string.

`$obj->data` is an object that has various properties some of which are empty arrays. Passing these into the `foreach` should work. i.e.

```
foreach($obj->data->clients as client) {
  // Do something here
}
```

Further, `$obj->data->formaspago` has exactly one element in the array, which is an object. You can access this object with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($obj->data->formaspago as formaspago) {
  print formaspago->idFormaPago; // Will print 7
  print formaspago->FormaPago; // Will print "quwuw"
  print formaspago->Dias; // Will print 1
  print formaspago->Cuotas; // Will print 1
  print formaspago->last_sync_date; // Will print nothing
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot but had to treat it like an array:  $obj= json_decode($json, true);